# Strongloop query based on a json object value

Tags: json, rest, strongloop

I am working with StrongLoop to define restful API calls.

My StrongLoop model looks like this:

```
"MyTransfer": {
      "type": [
        {
          "Fromamt":
          {
            "Amount": {
              "type": "number"
            },
            "CurrencyCd": {
              "type": "string"
            }
          },
          "Toamt": {
            "Amount": {
              "type": "number"
            },
            "CurrencyCd": {
              "type": "string"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
```

I would like to do a search based on the value for Fromamt.Amount and Toamt.Amount. My search is defined as:

```
FundsTransferLimit.search = function (fromamt, toamt, cb) {
    app.models.FundsTransferLimit.find({where: {Toamt: {Amount: toamt}, Fromamt: {Amount: fromamt}}}, function(err, fundsTransferLimits) {
      cb(null, fundsTransferLimits);
    });
}
```

and I have registered the remote method as follows:

```
 FundsTransferLimit.remoteMethod(
    'search', {
      accepts : [{
        arg : 'fromamt',
        type : 'number',
        required : false,
        http : {
          source : 'query'
        }
      },{
        arg : 'toamt',
        type : 'number',
        required : false,
        http : {
          source : 'query'
        }
      }
      ],
      returns : {
        arg : 'result',
        type : 'FundsTransferLimit',
        root : true
      },
      http : {
        verb : 'get',
        path : '/'
      },
      description : 'Retrieves FundsTransferLimit records'
    });
```

but it does not seem to use the fromamt and toamt query parameters at all. I'm guessing it might be my syntax. For anyone who has done this, please advise and thanks!

Anita

Comment: Have you tried a simple example like I have here: https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-example-app-logic/blob/master/common/models/car.js#L2-L13?

Comment: Superhkah - thanks for your reply. Yes, I have been successful in getting simple examples to work.